# What can I query to see if Windows is booted and done with updates?

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

My goal is to remotely check a group of computers (extensive list) not only to see if the server has rebooted (usually when it was last rebooting), but if Windows is fully up and running at the login screen, and it won't restart for further updates or still be installing updates.

I did find a service called AppReadiness, which stopped it until the server rebooted. I am concerned that if it is set to manual, it may not always start. Could somebody please confirm if this is a reliable service?

EDIT: As I'm writing this, I did find out that it was stopped until it says "Working on updates, 100% complete, Don't turn off your computer" but as the server hung on that message, the AppReadiness service started. Is there anything better to watch? I've read other answers on different questions say to check if C$ is available, but that is available sooner than AppReadiness is available.

The code that is being used to check the service:

```
$creds = Get-Credential -Message "Enter server credentials:" -UserName "SERVERNAME\Administrator"
Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName "SERVERIPADDRESS" -Credential $creds | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "AppReadiness"}
```

EDIT 2: Also, instead of monitoring services, I have also tried looking for processes like winlogon.exe and loginui.exe for guidance on the server's condition but I'm not receiving the results I'm looking to record. These processes show when the server is getting ready when I was hoping they would only show once the login GUI was visible.

EDIT 3:

This edit is for the answer by @Kelv.Gonzales who stated to check for the Windows Event Log "DHCPv4 client service is started" log entry. That doesn't work and is on par with other services and events that I monitored. It shows valid before the login screen.

[image: Image Showing Windows Is Working On Updates When Event Is Posted]

My code was:

```
$creds = Get-Credential -Message "Enter server credentials:" -UserName "SERVERNAME\Administrator"
$server = "IPADDRESSOFSERVER"

while($true)
{
    $event = Get-WmiObject Win32_NTLogEvent -ComputerName $server -Credential $creds -Filter "(logfile='System' AND eventcode = '50036')" | select -First 1
    $event.ConvertToDateTime($event.TimeWritten)
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where your code and show us the errors your are having. You can use a simple service watcher, that sends you an alert, email or text when they are running.

Comment: There isn't much code as I'm using WMI through PowerShell to grab the status of a Windows service, which also leads to not having an error. The problem is finding a service that doesn't start before the login screen. For this project, I can't modify the target server, only query it. I have updated my question with the one-liner PowerShell code I'm using to check the service.

Answer (score 3):

That one liner will just fire off once of course. Any reason why you are using WMI, instead of the built-in PowerShell cmdlet - [Get-Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service)?

My suggestion is use an WMI Event watcher, using what you already have in place but target the service and any dependent services and have that event notify you when the state is running.

[Use PowerShell to Monitor and Respond to Events on Your Server](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-monitor-and-respond-to-events-on-your-server)

This article is using PowerShell and VBScript to do this, but you can do this with all PowerShell.

You can have a temporary or permanent watcher.

[PowerShell and Events: WMI Temporary Event Subscriptions](https://learn-powershell.net/2013/08/02/powershell-and-events-wmi-temporary-event-subscriptions)

Those can get a bit deep, so, if they aren't for you, you can just use your one line in a Do Loop that stops after the service comes online.

Basic example:

```
$TargetHost = $env:COMPUTERNAME
do {
    $TargetOperation = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName $TargetHost  | 
    Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "AppReadiness"}
    "Checking host $TargetHost for service/process $($TargetOperation.Name)"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
} until (($TargetOperation).State -eq 'Running')
"Validation of host $TargetHost for service/process $($TargetOperation.Name) complete"

# Results

Checking host WS70 for service/process AppReadiness
Checking host WS70 for service/process AppReadiness
Checking host WS70 for service/process AppReadiness
Validation of host WS70 for service/process AppReadiness complete
```

You can of course add as many services or processes as you'd like using operation logic.

All the above applies to almost whatever you'd like to watch. Services, process, file-folder.

Or just use this script in the loop.

> [Get Remote Logon Status - Powershell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Remote-Logon-Status-d8c2318a)
>
> This script will return the logon status of the local or a remote
>   machine.   Return types include "Not logged on", "Locked", "Logged
>   on", and "Offline.
>
> The most useful part of this is to check whether a computer is in the
>   locked state,  although the other return types could also be useful.
>
> This is a simple function, and can easily be included in a larger
>   script.   The return types could be changed to numbers for the calling
>   script to more easily  parse the return value.
>
> ***Download: GetRemoteLogonStatus.ps1***

Comment: Thank you. I use WMI as I need to pass credentials to the target server as none of these servers are on the same domain the script is running from. I also guess this might not be the correct site as I was looking for something better than AppReadiness due to it starting before the login screen is ready (sometimes by many minutes).

Answer (score 3):

Would finding 0 updates queued accomplish what you need then? This [arcticle](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2016/06/23/finding-pending-updates.aspx) goes into detail on how to accomplish it.

To check if windows is ready to log in, can you query for the event log for 'DHCPv4 client service is started' - Event ID 50036 satisfy if windows is ready.

Comment: See edit number three. Unfortunately, this did not work.

Comment: Hmm I see. Can you check if Windows Modules Installer is not running? If it is then it might means that it is still updating since this is a manual startup. Seems to be triggered by TrustedInstaller.

Answer (score 2):

I spent a week searching for a solution for this issue.  I wanted to share what is currently my best solution, hopefully it helps someone.

@kelv-gonzales pointed me in the right direction with his comment about the `Windows Modules Installer` and `TrustedInstaller`.

## Breakdown of my solution

There exists a process called `TiWorker.exe` that is the Windows Modules Installer Worker process.  This is the process responsible for actually installing the Windows Update.  This process (from what I've observed) reliably runs throughout the duration of a Windows Update being installed.  Once the update has been installed and a pending reboot is required, this process stops and goes away.

When you reboot the machine to satisfy the pending reboot, the `TiWorker.exe` process is one of the very first processes to start while the machine is coming back up.  In some cases, depending on the nature of the update, will finish the installation of an update (that's the increasing percentage you see during boot-up) while the computer comes back up.  Once the login screen is available, this process typically remains running four roughly 2 minutes (from what I've observed).  After which, it stops and goes away.  I found that waiting these few minutes was a small price to pay for reliably knowing when updates have finished processing.

## My scripts logic

I was able to write a script that keys off of the existence of this service.  For example, below is a high-level flow of my script.

1. Initiate the installation of Windows Updates.
2. Wait for updates to finishing installing and for a pending reboot.
3. Once a pending reboot exists, wait until `TiWorker.exe` is no longer running and then trigger a reboot.
4. While the machine is rebooting, repeatedly check the status of the machine during the reboot.  While the machine is coming back up, `TiWorker.exe` will start back up to finish the update.  Keep waiting until `TiWorker.exe` is no longer running (typically, the update will finish and the OS will wait at the lock screen for about 2 minutes before this process stops).

## Code

I modified the code posted by @gabriel-graves to check for the `TiWorker.exe` process.

```
$creds = Get-Credential -Message "Enter server credentials:" -UserName "SERVERNAME\Administrator"
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -ComputerName "SERVERIPADDRESS" -Credential $creds | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "TiWorker.exe"}
```